# request nodejs module not supporting redirect for some url

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, request, npm

I am using request nodejs module to get html for a website, but is not working for some redirection website as below:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: "http://www.amwasia.com",
    headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'},
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    followAllRedirects: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
       console.log("body>>>>>>"+body)
    } else {
        console.log("error>>>>>>>>>" + error);
        console.log("response statusCode>>>>>>>>>" + response.statusCode);
        console.log("response body>>>>>>>>>" + response.body);
    }
});
```

This gives me this output

body>>>>>>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.amwmotors.com/">
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***This is not accurate html.***

This website is redirecting to this page http://www.amwmotors.com/

another example I have is website : http://www.pmat.or.th and is redirecting to page http://www.pmat.or.th/main/

which is also not giving the right output.

I have also tried without ***followAllRedirects: true*** in options.

please help?

Comment: When i curl http://www.amwasia.com I get the same output as you. What are you expecting?

Comment: when we open http://www.amwasia.com in browser, we will be redirected to http://www.amwmotors.com/, so I want to get html of this redirected site and the one we are getting is not right, you can check this by using inspect element or by using ctrl+u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can log your `body` var in:

```
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
   console.log("body>>>>>>"+body)
}
```

, it's because you're receiving a `200` status code, which isn't a redirect. If you tested the url `www.amwasia.com` through the browser and was redirected, it was done through the html `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.amwmotors.com/">
```

Through the request module, it seems that you're getting a `200`, and not a `3xx`.

Comment: so how can i get the html of redirected url with request module for this case.

Comment: Well, since the url you have doesn't redirects you automatically, but does it through the `html`, the only way I see would be to scrap the `html`, search for a `<meta>` tag and take the url from the `content` attribute.